# Installing an operating system from an .iso file

Tags: mount, installation

I am trying to install a build of Chromium OS on my PC. I do not have any spare disks or flash drives. I want to find a way from installing the .iso from Ubuntu Live CD. How would I go about doing this? My friend suggested mounting the .iso, but I don't know what he's talking about.

Comment: why don't you just burn the iso? and boot from it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unetbootin will set up grub2 to boot an iso directly from your hard disk.

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/how-to-boot-iso-with-grub2-easy-way.html

Answer (score 3):

potentially you could use QEMU to attach your real harddisk inside a virtual instance booted off that .iso you are willing to install. can be a bit tricky but it worked for me.

once booted from Ubuntu Live CD install qemu:

```
sudo apt-get install qemu
```

then download Chromium OS iso.
run QEMU telling it to boot off the .iso and use your real harddisk.

```
sudo qemu -drive file=/tmp/chromium-install.iso,if=ide,index=1,media=cdrom -hda /dev/sda[add partition number if you want to use one]
```

i have to warn you though that this might screw things up. you would be safer off by only using a partition of the harddisk dedicated for the install of Chromium OS. you might need to do some bootloader configuration if you consider installing on a partition.

good luck!

Comment: Use VirtualBox instead of quemu if you need a GUI.

Comment: i don't think you can easily make VirtualBox work with a 'raw' disk. there is a 'passthrough' option but i never got it to work reliably.